# AngularJS ng-click broken inside a popover

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angularjs

I'm trying to write a directive to load a partial html file, compile it against a scope & use it as the Bootstrap popover content.

However I'm stuck at a very basic step, write a hide() method on the popover scope so that I can easily close it using `ng-click=hide()`.

---

This has been solved & the plunker is now covering other issues ;-).

UPDATE : plunker to the rescue : http://plnkr.co/edit/QH3NQh?p=preview

```
.directive('uiPopover', ['$compile', '$http', function($compile, $http) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
        hide: '&hide' // did not understand what is this
    },
    link: function postLink(scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
        console.warn('postLink', arguments, this);

        // scope is the anchor scope
        scope.name = "Hello"; // Using {{name}} is working
        scope.hide = function() { // Using ng-click="hide()" is not working :(
            console.log('in');
            element.popover('hide');
        }

        $http.get(attr.uiPopover).success(function(data) {
            element.popover({
                content: $compile(data)(scope), // popover content will get a new scope that I need to put hide() on.
                html: true
            });
        });


    }
}
}]);
```

Comment: What happens without the `hide: '&hide'`? The `&` is just so you can call methods in the parent scope. It doesn't seem like you need that here. Also, including the HTML where you use the directive would be helpful too.

Comment: Yep, i do also think &hide is useless there, removing it does not solve this, i've built a jsfiddle to help you help me! ;-). http://jsfiddle.net/olouvignes/MZF3J/4/

Comment: I got rid of the `href="#"` on the anchor tag and now it closes, but it also shows `{"error": "Please use POST request"}`. Is this expected? Or is there still more not working?

Comment: That's not a solution, as you just leave the page that way!

Comment: Can you change the plunker back to what the solution was? Use a new one for new questions.

Comment: Yes please, what @DanielCompton said. I can't see what you changed to fix the popover.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [this google group thread](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/angular/zCPLGa6VtfM/discussion), in particular [Andy's fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F3nfK/23/).
The difficultly seems to be that the popover widget/component creates a new DOM element that is placed outside the scope where the ui-popover directive is.

Comment: @Olivier Seems as issue is not with popover div's place but that jQuery somewhere clones popover content. Thus you can compile popover content after popover is rendered. You can do this [for example](http://plnkr.co/edit/BFnWBO?p=preview) using $timeout with 0 delay.

Comment: Thank you so much ;-). You rocked my 2nd issue ;-). Updated the pLnker with your code & everything is fine.

Comment: Sadly the example is no longer working. It seems the URLs for the [external](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js) bootstrap [resources](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-popover.js) need updating.

Answer (score 14):

My solution is the same, but for whatever it's worth, this is the code snippet I end up using. Hope this helps!

```
//Initialize & config popover controls
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({ html : true })
    .click(function(ev) {
     //this is workaround needed in order to make ng-click work inside of popover
     $compile($('.popover.in').contents())($scope);
});
```

And don't forget to include $compile and $scope as dependency.

Comment: This solution looks more attractive and easy to use. Thanks

Comment: Problem of this solution is .click binds the content multiple times. Some times with a few click you see the function run more than 200 times as I saw this in Firefox console when I monitor execution of controller function on ng-click. It is better instead of using this just compile the contents in popover option like this:  element.popover({ content: $compile(data)(scope), html: true  });

Answer (score 0):

I had to use `$compile(tip.contents())(scope);` after the tip has been created (by binding "click"). Check the Plunker for the solution.

Comment: @VladimirStarkov I believe he is referring to the "[for example](http://plnkr.co/edit/BFnWBO?p=preview)" link in the comments of [the accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12217727/971556).

Answer (score 0):

look at [here](https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-strap/blob/master/src/directives/popover.js) how you can make you need and much more. i think it's awesome )

this is the part of library [Angular-Strap](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#/popover)