# Angularjs animate ngClick + ngShow with custom directive (mySlide)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, directive

I'm trying to get the same ultimate functionality as `ng-click` + `ng-show`, except that I want the show to slide in instead of suddenly appear by toggling `display: block/none;`. I've got the jQuery animate I need, and I've set up the `ng-click`. I've got 2 problems, but the second might be a result of the first:

#### Problem 1

`ng-click` does not change the value of `aside_users`. I saw [SO#12202067](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12202067/758177) which seems to be a similar situation, but I don't understand how/why their [custom directive](http://jsfiddle.net/F3nfK/23/) works and the native `ng-click` doesn't.

I see the `scope: { … }` after `restrict: 'A',`, but that appears to make `$scope` values available within the newly-created DOM element (my elements already exist and show up just fine, but no triggers/events are happening).

*infobox.html*

```
<aside
  class="users"
  ng-include src="'views/users.html'"
  my-slide={"direction":"left","condition":"aside_users"}
></aside>

<i
  class="icon icon-user"
  ng-click="aside_users=!aside_users"
  ng-init="aside_users=false"
></i>
```

The above code is a `$compile`'d template and elsewhere within the template I print out the value of the $scope parameter `aside_users` (prints `false`).

#### Problem 2

`my-slide` doesn't seem to be initiated/triggered (the logging of `'elm: ', elm` doesn't appear in Chrome's console). I verified that `directives.js` is linked in my `index.html` page.

**EDIT** I remembered to link `directives.js` in `index.html`, but I forgot to add it to the resources array in `app.js`.

**[Plunkr](http://embed.plnkr.co/DNoeXk)**

P.S. I'm not sure if `<aside attr={object}>` is strictly valid, but legitimate browsers seem to accept it in test cases (didn't bother to check IE). My alternate plan is to use 2 attributes: `<foo my-slide="direction" my-condition="boolean"></foo>`