# AngularJS ng-click event isn't fired in Bootstrap popover

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

The AngularJS ng-click event isn't fired in a Boostrap popover.

```
<button id="delAnnot" type="button" class="btn btn-default"  
         data-toggle="popover" data-html="true" data-placement="bottom" data-content="
         <button type='button' class='btn btn-danger' ng-click='vm.removeAnnotation(scenevm.sharedService.curAnnotation.ID)'>delete</button>">
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
</button>
```

I initialized my popover with a container so that the popover is within my angular controller:

```
$(".btn").popover({
    placement: 'bottom',
    trigger: 'click',
    container: '#sceneCtrl'
})
```

Comment: should you do it this way? can you use some angular directive because there are already tons of great directive for popover?

Answer (score 0):

For sure 'ng-lick' is not going to work try 'ng-click'. You can try as well using bootstrap directives http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ instead doing that in jQuery way.
Regards

Sylwester

Comment: that was a typo. I'll try to use angular-ui

Comment: the ui bootstrap directives do not support angular inside the popover

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this thread: [AngularJS ng-click broken inside a popover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12202067/angularjs-ng-click-broken-inside-a-popover)

And here is the code that worked for me:

```
//Initialize & config popover controls
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({ html : true })
    .click(function(ev) {
     //this is workaround needed in order to make ng-click work inside of popover
     $compile($('.popover.in').contents())($scope);
});
```

And don't forget to include $compile and $scope as dependency in your module.